# How do I call sink.fromFuture in a BLoC pattern?

Tags: sql, dart, flutter, bloc

I'm stuck in an this situation:
I'm trying to utilize a BLoC patten to handle a db,
but when I don't know how to call .fromFuture
in the sink of the Stream

here's the code:

```
class ClientBloc implements BlocBase {
  static final DatabaseHelper _db = DatabaseHelper();

  final _listController = StreamController<List<Client>>();
  Sink<List<Client>> get  sinkList => _listController.sink;
  Stream<List<Client>> get streamList => _listController.stream;

  final StreamController<Client> _saveClientCtrl = StreamController<Client>();
  Sink<Client> get  sinkSave => _saveClientCtrl.sink;

  ClientBloc(){
    sinkList.add(_getList());   <----ERROR HERE
    _saveClientCtrl.stream.listen(_saveClient);
  }

  static Future<List<Client>> _getList() async => await _db.getClientsList();

    @override
  void dispose() {
    _listController.close();
    _saveClientCtrl.close();
  }

  void _saveClient(data) {
    _db.saveClient(data);
    sinkList.add(_getList()); <----ERROR HERE
  }

}
```

the error obviously states

```
> The argument type 'Future<List<Client>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Client>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
_getList() → Future<List<Client>>
```

can you help me?
thank you in advance
Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to create another method?

Like this:

```
someMethod() async{
    List<Client> yourList = await _db.getClientsList();
    sinkList.add(yourList);
}
```

then insert that method to your constructor:

```
ClientBloc() {
    someMethod();
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you Jerome, it works as intended
(happy new year)